# Issues with Image selection from disk Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this form where I need to upload a **profilePic** and **companyLogo**. Earlier I faced some issues regarding updating images on the selection which I fixed using : `imageCache.clear()` & `imageCache.clearLiveImages()` and passing Unique key to `Image.file` widgets.

Now, the problem is, if I select the profile Pic then select the company Logo & When I send the images as Multipart in FormData, it uses the file which I selected later for **both**, i.e, if I select _companyLogo after _profilePic, it replaces _profilePic data with _companyLogo, however the displaying images remains correct for Image.file widget.

```
//Widgets using GestureDetector to call onAddProfilePic() and onAddCompanyLogo()

File _profilePic;
Key _keyProfilePic = Key('key1');
Image.file(
  _profilePic,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  key: _keyProfilePic,
)

File _companyLogo;
Key _keyCompanyLogo = Key('key2');
Image.file(
  _companyLogo,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  key: _keyCompanyLogo,
)


onAddProfilePic(){
  Utils.selectImage(context, (newPic) {
    if(newPic != null){
      _profilePic = newPic;
      _keyProfilePic = Key(Uuid().v4());
      setState(() {});
    }
  });
}

onAddCompanyLogo(){
  Utils.selectImage(context, (newPic) {
    if(newPic != null){
      _companyLogo = newPic;
      _keyCompanyLogo = Key(Uuid().v4());
      setState(() {});
    }
  });
}
```

The function **selectImage** is in Utils Class

```
static Future<void> selectImage(context, callback, {int minSize = 480, double ratioX = 1.0, double ratioY = 1.0}) async {
  int sourceSelected = await showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => DialogImagePicker());
  if(sourceSelected == null) return;
  var pickedImage = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: sourceSelected == 0 ? ImageSource.camera : ImageSource.gallery);
  if(pickedImage==null) return;

  File croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
    maxWidth: (minSize * ratioX).toInt(),
    maxHeight: (minSize * ratioY).toInt(),
    compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,
    sourcePath: pickedImage.path,
    aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: ratioX, ratioY: ratioY),
    compressQuality: 80,
    androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
        toolbarColor: kDarkBlueColor,
        toolbarTitle: 'Crop Image',
        hideBottomControls: true,
        toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white
    ),
  );
  if(croppedFile == null){
    return;
  }

  croppedFile = croppedFile.renameSync(path.join(path.dirname(croppedFile.path), 'image'+'.jpg'));
  print('Cropped file :$croppedFile');
  imageCache.clear();
  imageCache.clearLiveImages();
  callback(croppedFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, since I was cropping the image & was changing the **cropped file** name, which was replacing previous images with newly selected ones. Not renaming so fixed the issue.

Additional to this, no unique key or image cache clearance is required.

Updated code:

```
File _profilePic;
Image.file(
  _profilePic,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
)

File _companyLogo;
Image.file(
  _companyLogo,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
)


onAddProfilePic(){
  Utils.selectImage(context, (newPic) {
    if(newPic != null){
      _profilePic = newPic;
      setState(() {});
    }
  });
}

onAddCompanyLogo(){
  Utils.selectImage(context, (newPic) {
    if(newPic != null){
      _companyLogo = newPic;
      setState(() {});
    }
  });
}



static Future<void> selectImage(context, callback, {int minSize = 480, double ratioX = 1.0, double ratioY = 1.0}) async {
  int sourceSelected = await showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => DialogImagePicker());
  if(sourceSelected == null) return;
  var pickedImage = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: sourceSelected == 0 ? ImageSource.camera : ImageSource.gallery);
  if(pickedImage==null) return;

  File croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
    maxWidth: (minSize * ratioX).toInt(),
    maxHeight: (minSize * ratioY).toInt(),
    compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,
    sourcePath: pickedImage.path,
    aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: ratioX, ratioY: ratioY),
    compressQuality: 80,
    androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
        toolbarColor: kDarkBlueColor,
        toolbarTitle: 'Crop Image',
        hideBottomControls: true,
        toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white
    ),
  );
  if(croppedFile == null){
    return;
  }

  //croppedFile = croppedFile.renameSync(path.join(path.dirname(croppedFile.path), 'image'+'.jpg'));
  callback(croppedFile);
}
```